# Incorrect calulation (pairing chess players in a club)

Tags: combinatorics

I tried to calculate how many ways you can combine 20 chess players into pairs like this:
For example, if there is 1 pair, there is only 1 possible configuration. If you add another pair:
Take a random player (call him Jackson). He can be paired with three other players (Anne, Beth, Daniel). If Jackson plays Beth, then that leaves 1 pair to arrange in different ways. Since we know that 1 pair has just one possible configuration, and Jackson can pick three different players to play with, that means there are 3 possible configurations for 2 pairs. Using this, the result I got for 10 pairs was 685,906,650 potential combinations. But the answers for another question asking the same thing seem to all state the answer as 20!/10!. Anyone know why?

Comment: Huh. I get $$19\cdot17\cdot15\cdot13\cdot11\cdot9\cdot7\cdot5\cdot3\cdot1=\frac{20!}{2^{10}\cdot10!}=654,729,075.$$ What numbers did you multiply to get $685,906,650$? And where did you find the question where the answer was given as $20!/10!$?